# Converting a "map" object to a "SpatialPolygon" object

Tags: r, maps, r-maptools, r-sp

I am guessing there is a simple solution to the problem I have been having, but I am having some trouble.

I am trying to convert the following `map` object:

```
require(maps)
usa <- map("state")
```

into a `SpatialPolygon` object using the `map2SpatialPolygons` function:

```
require(maptools)
usa.sp <- map2SpatialPolygons(usa, IDs=usa$names,proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat"))
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in map2SpatialPolygons(usa, IDs = usa$names, proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat")) : 
  map and IDs differ in length
```

After some research, it looks like the IDs have length 63 and the `map` object has length 169 after applying the function `.NAmat2xyList(cbind(map$x, map$y))` (for which I cannot find the source to).

Anyone have any ideas? Here is the structure of the `usa` map object:

```
> str(usa)
List of 4
 $ x    : num [1:1705] -88.4 -88.1 -88 -87.9 -87.8 ...
 $ y    : num [1:1705] 30.4 30.4 30.8 30.6 30.3 ...
 $ range: num [1:4] -124.7 -67 25.1 49.4
 $ names: chr [1:63] "alabama" "arizona" "arkansas" "california" ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "map"
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just found some code in the text "Applied Spatial Data Analysis with R". It works great!

```
require(maps)
usa <- map("state", fill = TRUE)

require(sp)
require(maptools)
IDs <- sapply(strsplit(usa$names, ":"), function(x) x[1])
usa <- map2SpatialPolygons(usa, IDs=IDs, proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
```

Comment: When using the map by specifying the world-database and access the countries by their region name, regions could imho be accessed in a more general way:

germany <- map("world",regions="Germany",fill=TRUE)

As I understand only a limited set of databases is defined in the way you called it, Germany for example isn't. Nevertheless, your answer saved my day!

Answer (score 7):

Polygons have surface (area), therefore the key argument is `fill = TRUE` in

```
usa <- map('state', fill = TRUE)
```

Changing the argument value to TRUE stops the error message.

Comment: +1 Great point. It would be helpful if the ?map reference specified that the "fill" argument had this downstream effect. The way it is currently written (version 2.3-11), it reads like it only affects how the map is drawn on the screen.