# Difficulty opening a package data file of unknown type

Tags: r, io, format

I am trying to load the state map from the maps package into an R object. I am hoping it is a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame  or something I can turn into one after I have inspected it. However I am failing at the first step – getting it into an R object. I do not know the file type.

I first tried to assign the `map()` output to an R object  directly:

```
st_m <- maps::map(database = "state")
```

draws the map, but `str(st_m)` appears to do nothing, unless it is redrawing the same map.

Then I tried loading it as a dataset: `st_m <- data("stateMapEnv", package="maps")` but this just returns a string:

```
> str(stateMapEnv)
 chr "R_MAP_DATA_DIR"
```

I opened the maps directory `win-library/3.4/maps/mapdata/` and found what I think is the map file, “`state.L`”.

I tried reading it with scan and got an error message I do not understand:

```
scan(file = "D:/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/maps/mapdata/state.L")
Error in scan(file = "D:/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/maps/mapdata/state.L") : 
  scan() expected 'a real', got '#'
```

I then opened the file with Notepad++. It appears to be a binary or compressed file.

So I thought it might be an R data file with an unusual extension. But my attempt to load it returned a “bad magic number” error:

```
st_m <- load("D:/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/maps/mapdata/state.L")
Error in load("D:/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/maps/mapdata/state.L") : 
      bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
```

Observing that these responses have progressed from the unhelpful through the incomprehensible to the occult, I thought it best to seek assistance from the wizards of stackoverflow.

Comment: Don't understand what you mean by `str(st_m)` shows nothing. It seems to be just a list of x, y coordinates and state names

Comment: andrewH, what do you expect the `str` function does? I expect it to dump out a summary of the `str`ucture of an object, but not execute anything on its presentation. In contrast, some classes override their `print.classtype` function to do something special; for instance `p <- ggplot(...)` is quite fast, and does only assignment; the `print.ggplot` function is what actually *plots* it, which is its "printing side-effect", but `str(p)` does nothing like that, it just barfs out structure. (However, it would be possible to write `ggplot2::str.ggplot` and have some fun ...)

Comment: Look at the docs (`?maps::map`) to see that `maps::map("state")` returns an object of type `map` and optionally plots the shape. You'd want to then convert that object to a `Spatial*` object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a "map" object to a "SpatialPolygon" object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26062280/converting-a-map-object-to-a-spatialpolygon-object)

Answer (score 0):

This should be able to export the 'state' or any other maps dataset for you:

```
library(ggplot2)
state_dataset <- map_data("state")
```